# ¿Cómo parar un Event Listener?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un *event listener*

```js
(addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {})
```

¿Cómo puedo pararlo?, porque funciona cada vez que le doy **clic** desde que se ejecuta.

Quiero, que al apretarlo, ejecute una función y ya. Se pare, y pueda añadir luego otro *event listener*, que con lo que ha hecho la función del primero, el segundo haga otra cosa.

Comment: Puedes compartir el código de lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 3):

Para evitar que un evento se siga disparando debes removerlo del o los elementos al cual fue asignado. Para esto, utilice el método `removeEventListener` .

Por ejemplo:

```js
element.addEventListener('click', unaFuncion);

function unaFuncion(e) {
    e.target.removeEventListener('click', unaFuncion);

    //código a ejecutar una sola vez
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, creo que solo faltó aclarar que no se pueden remover eventos que usan funciones anónimas. +1